# how to add a property in object inside array of object if it matches the id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am newbie in angular, facing one issue if somebody helps then it will be appreciable
I have a array of objects like below

```js
signals = [{
'signalID': '123'
},{
'signalID': '233'
},{
'signalID': '333'
},{
'signalID': '433'
},{
'signalID': '533'
},{
'signalID': '633'
},{
'signalID': '733'
}]
```

I have an object like below

```js
signalOrder = {
333:1,
433:2,
533:3
}
```

i want to add an property to signals array as orderNo if signalId is matched in signalOrder object else orderNo should be null.
Result expected :

```js
signals = [{
'signalID': '123',
'orderNo':null
},{
'signalID': '233',
'orderNo':null
},{
'signalID': '333',
'orderNo':1
},{
'signalID': '433',
'orderNo':2
},{
'signalID': '533',
'orderNo':3
},{
'signalID': '633',
'orderNo':null
},{
'signalID': '733',
'orderNo':null
}]
```

I hope it should work with javascript map function but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()` to create the result you wish. For each signal item, we'll look up the `orderNo` in the signalOrder object. If not present, we'll set it to null.

```js
const signals = [{ 'signalID': '123' },{ 'signalID': '233' },{ 'signalID': '333' },{ 'signalID': '433' },{ 'signalID': '533' },{ 'signalID': '633' },{ 'signalID': '733' }];

const signalOrder = {
  333:1,
  433:2,
  533:3
}

const result = signals.map(({signalID}) => ({ 
    signalID,
    orderNo: signalOrder[signalID] || null
}))

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like :

```js
let signals = [{'signalID': '123'},{'signalID': '233'},{'signalID': '333'},{'signalID': '433'},{'signalID': '533'},{'signalID': '633'},{'signalID': '733'}];

let signalOrder = {333:1,433:2,533:3}

let mapped = signals.map(x=>{
  return {
    signalID:x.signalID,
    orderNo:signalOrder[x.signalID]
  }
})

console.log(mapped)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Angular or Typescript. It could be solved with vanilla JS Array methods.

Here is a method using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) test using OR `||`. Attempting `signalOrder[signal.signalID]` would return `undefined` for unavailable properties, which is falsy. In these cases, `null` would be used.

Try the following

```js
const signals = [{ 'signalID': '123' },{ 'signalID': '233' },{ 'signalID': '333' },{ 'signalID': '433' },{ 'signalID': '533' },{ 'signalID': '633' },{ 'signalID': '733' }]
const signalOrder = { 333:1, 433:2, 533:3 }

const result = signals.map(signal => ({
  ...signal,
  orderNo: signalOrder[signal.signalID] || null
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
signals = [{
'signalID': '123'
},{
'signalID': '233'
},{
'signalID': '333'
},{
'signalID': '433'
},{
'signalID': '533'
},{
'signalID': '633'
},{
'signalID': '733'
}];

signalOrder = {
333:1,
433:2,
533:3
};

signals.map(obj => {
  if(obj.signalID in signalOrder){
    obj.orderNo = signalOrder[obj.signalID]
  }
  else{
    obj.orderNo = null
  }
})

console.log(signals)
```

You are right. We can use JS map function to resolve this. I have verified the below code, you can try this:

```
  signals.map(obj => {
  if(obj.signalID in signalOrder){
    obj.orderNo = signalOrder[obj.signalID]
  }
  else{
    obj.orderNo = null
  }
})
```